# pam_exec in linux mint does not work

Tags: scripting, login, pam

I am trying to run a script when a user logs in using pam_exe.so.

`/etc/pam.d/common-sesion` is:

```
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_sss.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
session optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
session optional    pam_ck_connector.so nox11

session required    pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077 

# end of pam-auth-update config

session optional    pam_exec.so   debug seteuid log=/tmp/pam_exec.log /usr/local/createlink
```

The createlink script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -L /home/$PAM_RUSER/zdrive ]; then
    ln -s /mnt/dcs/home/$PAM_RUSER /home/$PAM_RUSER/zdrive
fi
```

and

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/createlink
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200 Apr 18 15:10 createlink*
```

However with this the user is not allowed to login.. it shows authentication failure when logging in graphically

when i su -  from the command line i get a "su: permission denied error". the log file  /tmp/pam_exec.log is not created.

Running linux mint 18

Losing my mind over this... Any help is welcome!!!!

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Please show us the output of `ls -l /usr/local/createlink`. Also, where exactly is the first code snippet (the PAM configuration) from?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The pam config is from /etc/pam.d/common-sesion. The output of  ls -l is` '-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  200 Apr 18 15:10 createlink* `

Comment: I tried - su -c "pam-auth-update --force" , because I had made some changes to the config files... and probably didn't have to if I just wanted to reload config files.. But I found out pam-authority can be enabled or disabled for every layer of Posix interaction, knwiM? Still didn't work for me to enable everything and their grandma to host a party! Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @vic there you go: an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for logins now all failing is the exit status from your script. If your script returns non-zero it is considered by `pam_exec` to be a failure, and the session setup may be aborted. (The actual determination to abort is unobvious; it seems to be to do with the number of `optional` modules involved in the stack.)

Looking at your code, you're using `$PAM_RUSER` instead of `$PAM_USER` to identify the user account that is logging in. `$PAM_RUSER` is (usually) empty, so your code becomes equivalent to this

```
if [ ! -L /home/zdrive ]; then
    ln -s /mnt/dcs/home/ /home/zdrive
fi
```

If the link *does not* initially exist, it's created, and the exit status of the script is good. The second and subsequent times the script is called, the the link *will* initially exist, so the test fails and that is the implied exit status of the script.

You can fix this by amending your code slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -L "/home/$PAM_USER/zdrive" ]; then
    ln -s "/mnt/dcs/home/$PAM_USER" /home/$PAM_USER/zdrive"
fi
exit 0
```

One other piece of useful debugging is the system logger. Don't discount it. For example, placing this line immediately after the `#!` line will give you information in `/var/log/user.log` or your distribution's equivalent:

```
logger -t "${0/*\/}" "id=$(id); PAM_RHOST=$PAM_RHOST, PAM_RUSER=$PAM_RUSER, PAM_SERVICE=$PAM_SERVICE, PAM_TTY=$PAM_TTY, PAM_USER=$PAM_USER, PAM_TYPE=$PAM_TYPE."
```

Example output for `ssh roaima@localhost whoami`:

```
Jul  4 22:48:56 vml1 pam_exec_test.sh: id=uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root); PAM_RHOST=localhost, PAM_RUSER=, PAM_SERVICE=sshd, PAM_TTY=ssh, PAM_USER=roaima, PAM_TYPE=open_session.
Jul  4 22:48:56 vml1 pam_exec_test.sh: id=uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root); PAM_RHOST=localhost, PAM_RUSER=, PAM_SERVICE=sshd, PAM_TTY=ssh, PAM_USER=roaima, PAM_TYPE=close_session.
```